# Listar todas as propriedades de um objeto C#?

Tags: c#, propriedade, reflexão, recursão

Preciso escrever todas as propriedades primitivas de um objeto C# independente de quantos "níveis" eu entre nesses objetos.

Eu tenho o seguinte objeto em Javascript:

```
var objeto = {
  propriedade:{
    valor:42
  },
  atributo:"foo"  
}
```

Então para acessar todas as propriedades dele recursivamente, faço o seguinte:

```
function PrintAllProperties(obj){
      for(var prop in obj){
          if(typeof obj[prop]==="object")
             PrintAllProperties(obj[prop]);
          else
             console.log(obj[prop]);
         }
} PrintAllProperties(objeto);
```

Com isso a saída é formada por todas as propriedades com valor primitivo não importando a quantidade de níveis que tiveram de ser acessados daquele objeto "pai" ( [exemplo funcionando](http://jsbin.com/sixibeduqi/edit?html,js,console,output) )

**Como fazer isso em C#?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria algo assim:

```
public void PrintProperties(object obj, int indent)
{    
    if (obj == null) return;
    string indentString = new string(' ', indent);
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        var elems = propValue as IList;
        if (elems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in elems)
            {
                PrintProperties(item, indent + 3);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", indentString, property.Name);

                PrintProperties(propValue, indent + 2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", indentString, property.Name, propValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Tirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20554262/1314276), com algumas modificações. Isto imprime as propriedades, indentando em console.

Comment: Nota que isso só vai listar as propriedades públicas.

Comment: @dcastro Coloquei com todas as `BindingFlags`. Espero não ter esquecido de nada. Obrigado!